# Why is the acceleration of the boulder and pallet half that of the truck

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration

While working on some homework I accidentally seem to have reached a bit of a mental block on this relatively simple problem.

> A 5000-lb truck is used to lift a 1000-lb boulder sitting on a 200-lb pallet A. Knowing the acceleration of the truck is $\text{1 m/s}^2$. Determine (a) the horizontal force between tires and the ground, (b) the force between the boulder and the pallet.

I’m not asking to solve this, I can actually find multiple copies of the solution online. But all of them just take as an additional assumption:

$$a_{boulder}=a_{pallet}$$

This makes sense as they are essentially connected for the benefit of this problem (I’m also not really sure at what point that assumption breaks down).

My question is that how do we arrive at

$$ a_{boulder} = a_{pallet} = \text{0.5 m/s}^2 $$

I’m assuming that (given the image accompanying this problem) we are making an assumption that for each time interval $t$ the truck moves some distance $x$, and the rope is doubled up and only moves $\frac{1}{2}x$. However I don’t necessarily feel satisfied by that and trying to model that assumption in my head isn’t convincing me.

Are my assumptions here valid? Is there another way of looking at this that might be more understandable than the mental model I’ve constructed?

[image: Figure from problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these additional assumptions can be called **hidden constraints** of the problem. $a_{boulder}=a_{pallet}$ because they always have the same height in your problem, i.e. $h_{boulder}=h_{pallet}$. Take second derivatives on both sides an you will conclude $a_{boulder}=a_{pallet}$.

As for why $a_{pallet}=1/2 a_{truck} = 0.5 m/s^2$, consider *conservation of rope length*. If your truck moves a distance $x_{truck}$, the horizontal part of the rope must also increase by the same length, and thus the verticle rope length must decrease by the same length. Since the verticle rope is double-fold, decreasing its length by $x_{truck}$ only raises the height of the pellet and boulder by an height of $h_{pallet} = 1/2 x_{truck}$. Take second derivatives on both sides an you will conclude $a_{pallet}=1/2a_{truck}$.

Comment: Ah so essentially I was on the right track? I was having a bit of trouble mentally picturing the behavior of the double fold rope, and why say it wouldn’t be possible to have some other behavior. I think the easiest way to understand it now that I think about it a bit more is that rope = x length + 2*folded portions+constant offsets not modeled. Therefore a dx must couple with 1/2 reduction in folded. Which now that I think about it, I think my book modeled it that way at some point and I had confused myself here.

Comment: Exactly! You are on the right track and is concerned with an important problem in modeling, which is to express constraints explicitly. Constraints don't always hold even in the same physics model. For example, if the driver suddenly steps on the brake and the truck stops quickly, the rope will become loose for a moment you can no longer assume the rope length constraint.